# python, change value of matrix eye

Tags: python, numpy

I have python code like below

```
import numpy as np

II = np.eye(3, 3, k=-1)
II[0,0] = 0
II[0,1] = 0
print(II)
```

and got the result

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

expected result that I want to is

```
 [[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ -1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  -1.  1.]]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Why did you expect that result? It doesn't make any sense. Why would there be ones on the main diagonal? Why would there be negative values anywhere?

Comment: I still on process to make matrix in order to solve tikhonov regularization, so i must make matrix like that @user2357112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like as follows.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.eye(3, 3)
B = np.eye(3, 3, k=-1)
B[B>0]=-1
C = A + B
C[0, 0] = 0
print(C)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  1.]]
```